# Does CommonsHttpSolrServer have good performance?

Tags: java, solr, apache-commons, solrj

I need to know the performance between EmbeddedSolrServer and CommonsHttpSolrServer.

***EmbeddedSolrServer:***

```
File home = new File("C:\\workspace\\SolrWithMultipleCore\\solr");
File f = new File( home, "solr.xml" );
CoreContainer container = new CoreContainer();
container.load( "C:\\workspace\\SolrMultipleCore\\solr", f );
EmbeddedSolrServer server = new EmbeddedSolrServer( container,"core1");
EmbeddedSolrServer server1 = new EmbeddedSolrServer( container,"core2");
String query=params.getParams("q");
String query1=params.getParams("q1");
SolrQuery solrquery=new SolrQuery(query);
QueryResponse rsp1 = server.query(solrquery);
QueryResponse rsp2 = server1.query(solrquery);
```

***CommonsHttpSolrServer:***

```
SolrServer httpServer = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(url);
QueryResponse rsp1=httpServer.query(q);
SolrServer httpServer1 = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(url1);
QueryResponse rsp2=httpServer1.query(q1);
```

Which is best EmbeddedSolrServer or CommonsHttpSolrServer? the two core i meantion has different schema.
I need to know what is  MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.

Comment: Usually it is recommended dedicated server for solr. It scales, and fits most use cases. Reference :"When should I use Embedded Solr" in a book "Solr 1.4 Enterprise
Search Server"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Embedded is obviously faster because it doesn't have any HTTP or serialization overhead. That doesn't mean you should always use embedded. See the [EmbeddedSolr wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr).

About MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager, the [CommonHttpSolrServer javadocs](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CommonsHttpSolrServer.html#CommonsHttpSolrServer%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient%29) explain:

> The connection manager for the client
>   should be a
>   MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager if
>   this client is being reused across
>   SolrServer instances, or of multiple
>   threads will use this SolrServer.

Comment: if it possible can you please add some sample on MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager or else link which it describe? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Syed: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/questions-on-CommonsHttpSolrServer-and-MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager-td837695.html

Comment: can you help me in which i had added ? if possible

Comment: @Syed: changing a question to completely alter its original meaning is frowned upon. Moreso if it has already been answered. Instead, please create a new question.

Comment: About the MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager; when instantiating the CommonHttpSolrServer without the HttpClient param, the constructor of the CommonHttpSolrServer will create a new one using the MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager. (this is not mentioned in the javadocs)